# Parse information from .XML and use it in Xcode

Tags: xml, xcode, parsing

I'm very new to xcode/objc, just used delphi until last week. Now I need your help.
How can I parse informations off an .XML?
Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Songs>
    <Song id="1">
        <title>Heja BVB</title>
        <author>Dortmunder Ultras</author>
        <Link>LINK TO THE SONG</Link>
    </Song>
    ...
    </Songs>
```

I need to put the title and the author on a round rect button as a caption. The link is going to be opened with an UIWebView. I have several buttons for different fan chants of football teams, which will be updated regularly. My idea was to parse the information when the app loads and save them to some variables, and name all the buttons with the title/author-information. 
But I don't know how to save .XML strings in a variable. I'm using Xcode 4.2.1.Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I just completed an app that parses XML data in a few different ways; into tables (with different XML attributes filling different labels on the cells), into a text box, and into a scroll view with images. Everything I needed to know came from the following tutorial. It took minor tweaking to get it to XCode 4.2 standards, but it was very easy to modify. If you need more specific guidance, I'm happy to elaborate.

http://www.lonhosford.com/lonblog/2011/05/11/xcode-4-iphone-mountains-of-the-usa-tutorial-lesson-1-setup-the-app/